# When my server receives a request with the header "Accept: application/ld+json", return a specific file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, json-ld, response-headers

I want to be able to do the following:

When my Apache server receives a request with the header:

```
Accept: application/ld+json
```

I want to return the file "./jsonld", with the header

```
ContentType: application/ld+json
```

This is what I have so far :

```
<If "%{HTTP:Accept} =~ m#application/ld\+json#">
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^ /jsonld [L]

   Header always set Content-Type "application/ld+json"

</If>
```

Comment: To clarify, `jsonld` is a physical file? (_Aside:_ Any reason you are not using a file extension? A `.jsonld` ext would probably avoid you having to force the Content-Type header.)

Comment: It is a physical file but I may make it a directory in the future. I am not using a file extension because this is an attempt to make it a standardized url (within my organization). I don't want file extensions as it's not meant to be a file, just a URI.

Comment: @MrWhite I used your file extension suggestion and that made it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddType application/ld\+json .jsonld

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} application/ld\+json
RewriteRule ^ jsonld.jsonld
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an Apache `<If>` expression or `Header` directive as you can do this using mod-rewrite only. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} application/ld\+json
RewriteRule ^ jsonld [T=application/ld+json,END]
```

Every request that sends the appropriate `Accept` header is rewritten to `/jsonld`. This includes requests for `/jsonld` itself (to ensure the correct mime-type is sent back in the response).

The `T` flag forces the mime-type (`Content-Type` header) that will be sent with the response.

Assuming this is all located in the document root (`.htaccess` and `jsonld` files) then the slash prefix on the substitution string is intentionally omitted.

The `END` flag (Apache 2.4) serves to prevent a rewrite loop.